# Merging squashed commits to feature from master

Tags: git, github, merge

Lets say I make 30 commits in branch `cool-feature` that I pulled from master.

I merge `cool-feature` into `master` using the merge squash function in github. The 30 commits turn into 1.

In my eagerness, I then start to write another feature onto `cool-feature` because I forgot to make a new feature branch off `master` because I'm an idiot.

If no other commits are made to `master`, and I merge `master` into `cool-feature` again, I catch all sorts of merge conflict hell, even though I technically already have `master` in my branch: its just that I have a different history in `cool-feature` because of the commit squash. I wouldnt get the grief if I hadnt squashed the commits.

Im going to keep squashing on my merges to `master`, is there a clean way to handle the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by `git stash`ing my changes, making a new branch off `develop`, and `git stash apply`ing.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following situation:

```
A-B-C-S              # master
     \
      D-E-F-X-Y-Z    # cool-feature
```

Where `D,E,F` were commits that got squashed into `S` and subsequently merged into `master`.

`X,Y,Z` are the overeager commits to `cool-feature` after it has been squashed and merged.

What you can do is run

```
git rebase -i S
```

where `S` is the SHA1 of the squashed commit. You will be shown a text file

```
pick D commit message
pick E commit message
pick F commit message
pick X commit message
pick Y commit message
pick Z commit message
```

If you now simply drop all lines corresponding to commits contained in `S` (the first three, `D,E,F` in this case) you will rebase the rest of the branch on top of `S`:

```
A-B-C-S             # master
       \
        X-Y-Z       # new cool-feature
```

After doing that you can merge master into `cool-feature` or vice versa.

Comment: The first diagram is not a correct representation of a squash merge. There is no `M`, and `master` points at `S`.  The proposed rebase will still work, but the result diagram is also incorrect.